# User password expiration

Tags: api, user

Is there any way to programmatically detect when the user password is expired?
There are no password expiration datetime fields on User object, I could only find Profile settings "Never expire password".

Comment: Under which context are you interested in? SOAP API? REST API? For the current user? For any arbitrary user? Could you give us some more info?

Comment: You can find out if it is expired for a specific user but I do not see anything that lets you find out when via api..https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_user_password.htm

Answer (score 2):

If you're only interested in determining if the user's password is currently expired, you can log in via the SOAP API; see the [LoginResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login_loginresult.htm) documentation:

> passwordExpired | boolean | Indicates whether the password used during the login attempt is expired (true) or not (false). If the password has expired, then the API returns a valid sessionId, but the only allowable operation is the setPassword() call.

So, if you check passwordExpired, and it is true, you can prompt the user set a new password (which you would set with setPassword), and then they can continue working normally.

If you're using an OAuth login flow for a mobile application (typically REST calls), the UI handles the expired password situation for you automatically; when you receive the access token, it will be for an active user with an unexpired password.

Other API types will offer a similar type of return type; please check the relevant documentation for the API you're trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it using **REST API**. There is a field called `LastPasswordChangeDate`. So, depending on organization password policy you can determine the expiration date by adding days.

You can get this field by calling out to:

```
instance/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/User/00590000001UDjyR
```

**Response**

[image]